# Explicit computation of Ext groups

Tags: algebraic-geometry

**The bold parts are edited according to the answer.**

Consider the following situation. Let $X$ be a K$3$ surface and $C\subset X$ a smooth rational curve such that $C^2=-2$. The claim is that $\dim\,Ext^i(\mathcal{O}_C,\mathcal{O}_C)=1$ if $i=0,2$ and it is $0$ otherwise.

Since $C\sim\mathbb{P}^1$ and the canonical bundle of $X$ is trivial I can get that $\dim\,Ext^i(\mathcal{O}_X,\mathcal{O}_C)=1$ if $i=0,2$ and $0$ otherwise **(as the answer suggests, this is false: it is always zero dimensional a part in degree zero)**. This suggests to look at the short exact sequence
$$0\longrightarrow\mathcal{O}_X(-C)\longrightarrow\mathcal{O}_X\longrightarrow\mathcal{O}_C\longrightarrow0$$
and apply the functor $\rm{Hom}(-,\mathcal{O}_C)$.

Now I am stuck. I guess that $Ext^i(\mathcal{O}_X(-C),\mathcal{O}_C)=0$ for every $i$, but I cannot see it **(again this claim is false: it is zero dimensional everywhere a part in degree 1)**. I reckon that I should use the fact that $C^2=-2$ but I don't know how.

Any suggestions, comments, etc.. will be very appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that for any quasicoherent sheaf $F$ on any scheme $X$, $Ext^i(\mathcal{O}_X,F) = H^i(F)$. So I don't think your statement about $Ext^i(\mathcal{O}_X,\mathcal{O}_C) = H^i(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1})$ is correct: it is 1-dimensional for $i=0$ and zero for $i=1,2$.

Similarly, $Ext^i(\mathcal{O}_X(-C),\mathcal{O}_C) = Ext^i(\mathcal{O}_X,\mathcal{O}_C(C)) = H^i(\mathcal{O}_C(C)).$ And, since $\mathcal{O}_C(C) \cong \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(-2)$, this cohomology group is $0$ for $i=0$, 1-dimensional for $i=1$ and zero for higher $i$.

Also clearly $Ext^0(\mathcal{O}_C,\mathcal{O}_C)$ is 1-dimensional.

Now plug these into the long exact sequence to find that $Ext^1(\mathcal{O}_C,\mathcal{O}_C) = 0$ (it is enclosed between two zeroes) and $Ext^2$ is 1-dimensional (for similarly easy reasons).

Comment: Of course I was wrong, what a stupid! I was thinking at the integral cohomology (maybe because it was exactly the result..). By the way, can I ask you what are you using when you state $Ext^i(\mathcal{O}_X(-C),\mathcal{O}_C)=Ext^i(\mathcal{O}_X,\mathcal{O}_C(C))$? Thank you very much!

Comment: Hartshorne III.6.7. Glad I could be of help!